# Spread Promise and extend in a new Object

Tags: javascript, promise, lodash

I have some Promises that give me back Objects.

Now I want to merge/extend them into a new Object therefore I use [Lodash's extend](https://lodash.com/docs#assignIn).

```
var whenEverythingIsDone = Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise, ...])
                          .spread(_.extend);
```

Now I have the problem that I didn't make a NEW Object just extended firstPromise.

I tested this,

```
var whenEverythingIsDone = Promise.all([{}, firstPromise, secondPromise, ...])
                          .spread(_.extend);
```

and it worked as far as I can tell.

Is this a good solution?

Could there be errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine, `Promise.all` does `Promise.resolve` all array items and an empty object will be no problem.

I would find it cleaner though to use [partial application](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) explicitly:

```
var whenEverythingIsDone = Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise, …])
                           .spread(_.partial(_.extend, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like it! very clean and concise... I don't foresee any problem if none of the promises resolves to something else than an object